# Storage Integration / Expansion Options?

Tags: macos, mac, apfs

Every 3 to 4 months, my Mac storage is filling up, and it seems the only way to free space is to recover.  It's becoming annoying to recover constantly.  I simply need more storage but don't have the option to expand the storage on the inside (because the drive is soldered).

Mac 27" 2021 Intel with Monterey

I have an internal SSD 500GB and an external 1TB M2 drive on USB-C.

I was initially trying to create a JBOD with the internal drive and an external M2 to boot my Mac but found that this is a difficult task / not possible.  I tried installing on an external and using SuperDuper! to clone the drive onto the JBOD, but it's not even detected as a boot drive. (I know this isn’t the greatest idea, but I was trying it anyway). So, I am trying to see if there is a way to store “Data” and “Library” on an external drive and keep the rest of the system on the internal drive.

Is this possible? Is it a good idea? Should I just do data?

I would ultimately like to have 1 container with everything over JBOD, but I am open to any ideas to help manage storage better.  (aside from getting a new Mac that is!)

Any suggestions would be great. Thanks!

Comment: When I had a large amount of data and a smaller drive I just plugged in an external drive, copied my entire profile over to the external drive and then selected the copied profile (right click username in System Preferences) on the external drive as my new profile. Worked a treat.

Comment: IMHO I cannot see a new mac would cure your storage problem - a 1TB would just give you 6 months and 2TB about 12... You need to consider what needs to be on the local drive and what can be stored on an external or on the cloud.

Comment: I am trying the user folder on the external drive.  It's fast enough to read and right that I shouldn't have an issue.  Hopefully, this will help me for now.  And I am going to look at another external for long-term storage.  I have an unraid server, it just seems to take forever to get what I need... but that might just be the long-term solution for storing less-needed files.